# Launching usb_cam on a remote Machine

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic, camera, remote-launch, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS-Community,

as the title already says I want to Launch the usb_cam Node on a Raspberry Pi from my main Computer. Although there are many Question regarding the usb_cam not working, I can't find one that deals with the `<machine>` tag. :(

The Launch file works on my main Computer and the Pi locally (so i guess the param are not the problem), but if I use the `<machine>` tag to start it remotely i get the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [usb_cam/usb_cam_node.cpp]: usb_cam
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/kinetic/stacks
```

launch file:

```
<launch>
  <machine name="pi" address="192.168.0.48" env-loader="/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh" user="me" default="true" />
  <node name="usb_cam_2" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node.cpp" output="screen">
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
    <param name="image_width" value="1920" />
    <param name="image_height" value="1080" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

I think the problem lies here: `env-loader="/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh"`, but as I am kinda new to ROS I don't know what to do about it. :(

Greetings Jamrock

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266048/launching-usb_cam-on-a-remote-machine/) by [Jamrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/31110/jamrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-11**:
Please use the *Preformatted Text* button next time to format console copy-pastes and code and launch files. It's the one with `101010` on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> type="usb_cam_node.cpp"
> ```

I'm not saying this will resolve all your issues, but a C++ source file is not something that can be launched.

You'll want to launch the *binary*, ie: `usb_cam_node` (no `.cpp`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jamrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/31110/jamrock/) on 2017-07-13**:
You guessed correct, it did not change anything regarding the Error. Nevertheless i changed it and thank you for the fast answer. :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-13**:
It did not change anything? That is strange, as it should now no longer be looking for the `usb_cam/usb_cam_node.cpp` node.

**Comment by [Jamrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/31110/jamrock/) on 2017-07-14**:
I really don't know why it didn't change anything, but I think it doesn't find the package at all. I tried to use the `machine` tag with the `turtlesim_node` from the tutorial on my computer and the `turtle_teleop_key` on the Pi. Although I couldn't move the turtle I didn't get any errors.